# How do I update Dynamics CRM with from flat file via Kingswaysoft?

Tags: migration, microsoft-dynamics-crm, ssis, crm

I've been trying for some time to update existing leads in CRM via .csv files and the migration tool by Kingswaysoft.
I am trying to update fields based on one key column, updating old leads and importing new leads.

Now, how do I set up the connections with the Kingswaysoft migration tool in SSIS, so that I can do the previously explained?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at our [Help Manual](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm/help-manual)? You can find instructions for how to connect to your CRM instance there, instructions will vary slightly depending on your server. You would then use the Flat File Source to read from your .csv file. And the CRM Destination Component to write to CRM. It sounds like you will want to select Upsert as your action type if you are both updating and importing from 1 .csv file. You can then select Primary Key or Manually Specify for your matching criteria, for Manually Specify you can select the field in the columns page.

Hope that helps.